# How to explain why $(1-i)^{2n+1} = a_n - ib_n$

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing

I've just proved by induction that $(1+i)^{2n+1} = a_n + ib_n$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are $2^n$. And now I need to explain why $(1-i)^{2n+1} = a_n - ib_n$ and deduce from it why $|P_n(1)=2^n|$ where $P_n(X) = \frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}}{2i}$ I have no ideas how to proceed.

Comment: The first claim is wrong, but the technique to prove the second (also wrong) is the same.

Comment: What is $(1\pm i)^{2n}$ ?

Comment: Hint : $1-i = \sqrt(2) (cos(-\pi/4) + isin(-\pi/4))$ and apply De Moivre's formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you prove that $(1+i)^{2n+1}=a_n+ib_n$, for real $a_n,b_n$, then taking the conjugates shows that
$$
(1-i)^{2n+1}=a_n-ib_n
$$
There's no other computation to do.

Let's try to see what $a_n$ and $b_n$ should be. For $n=0$, we have $a_n=b_n=1$. Then
$$
a_{n+1}+ib_{n+1}=(1+i)^{2n+3}=(a_n+ib_n)(1+i)^2=2i(a_n+ib_n)=-2b_n+2ia_n
$$
Hence you have $b_{n+1}=2a_n$ and $a_{n+1}=-2b_n$.

However, there's a straighter path: $(1+i)^2=2i$, so you have
$$
(1+i)^{2n+1}=2^{n+1}i^n(1+i)
$$
and it should now easy to compute $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: @RoyalValue Re egreg's answer, given $z = (x + iy), w = (u + iv)$ with $\overline{z} = (x - iy)$ and $\overline{w} = (u - iv)$ then you can routinely verify that $\overline{\left(z \times w\right)} = \overline{\left(z\right)} \times \overline{\left(w\right)}.$